# GDB print array after passing to function only prints first value, but array still intact

Tags: c++, arrays, gdb

When I pass an array to a function, GDB doesn't show list of values anymore, only a memory address. I can still iterate the array, but I haven't found a way to dereference it to get back to the list. How would I do that?

```
void dostuff(int foo[8], int size_of_foo) {
    int i = 0;
    i++;
}

int main() {
    int foo[8] = {6, 0, 9, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4};
    dostuff(foo, sizeof(foo));
}
```

GDB says (1st breakpoint in main, 2nd in dostuff):

> Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1-ubuntu
>
> At /home/lash/programming/workspace/Codeblocks Tests/main.cpp:19
>
> p foo
>
> **$1 = {6, 0, 9, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4}**
>
> Continuing... At /home/lash/programming/workspace/Codeblocks Tests/main.cpp:14
>
> p foo
>
> **$2 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe590**
>
> p *foo
>
> **$3 = 6**

I'm using gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All arrays decays to a pointer to the first element once passed to a function. You can still use array-indexing syntax when using pointers though.

Also note that using `sizeof` on an array gives you the size of the array *in bytes*, and not the number of elements in the array.

Comment: In GDB, in a addition to indexing individual elements, you could also print arrays like this: `p foo[0]@8` when you know the number of elements and have a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

you can dereference array elements using

```
p ((int*)0x7fffffffe590)[5]
```

e.g. to print the 6th element.